# Composer install fails: react/http dev-master requires react/socket

Tags: composer-php

While running the command "composer install" i get these problems:

```
$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for react/http dev-master#cd15204bd15d106d7832c680e4fb0ca0ce2f5e30 -> satisfiable by react/http[dev-master].
- react/http dev-master requires react/socket ^1.0 || ^0.8.3 -> satisfiable by react/socket[v0.8.3, v0.8.4, v0.8.5, v0.8.6] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
Problem 2
- react/http dev-master requires react/socket ^1.0 || ^0.8.3 -> satisfiable by react/socket[v0.8.3, v0.8.4, v0.8.5, v0.8.6] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- php-pm/php-pm dev-master requires react/http dev-master#cd15204bd15d106d7832c680e4fb0ca0ce2f5e30 -> satisfiable by react/http[dev-master].
- Installation request for php-pm/php-pm dev-master -> satisfiable by php-pm/php-pm[dev-master].
```

[used composer.json](https://static.vvcc.de/2017/composer.json)

System:

```
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.1 (stretch)
Release:        9.1
Codename:       stretch
```

Anybody here who knows how to solve these issues? Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your `composer.json` by

- lowering `minimum-stability` to `dev`
- setting `prefer-stable` to `true` (to still pull in stable packages if they are available)

For example:

```
{
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Then run:

```
$ composer require react/http:dev-master --update-with-dependencies
```

For reference, see:

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#prefer-stable
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require

Comment: @roombahacker How about sharing your `composer.json` above?

Comment: sorry, had to learn how comments work...
`Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.`
[my composer.json](https://static.vvcc.de/2017/composer.json)